# PHP Array (just one result)

Tags: php, arrays

In my loop, I have only one result.

The array result:

```
   array(3) {
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
         ["qty"]=> int(2)
       }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
        ["qty"]=> int(3)
       }
    [2]=>
      array(1) {
        ["qty"]=> int(4)
      }
    }
```

If I write this inside the loop, it displays just one one result:

```
var_dump('Key=' . $key .' - Value=' . $value['qty']);
```

My loop:

```
foreach ($this->products as $key => $value) {

        $QProducts = $this->db->prepare('select p.products_id,
                                                pd.products_name,
                                                p.products_model
                                          from :table_products p,
                                               :table_products_description pd
                                          where p.products_id = :products_id
                                          and p.products_id = pd.products_id
                                        ');

        $QProducts->bindInt(':products_id', $key);
        $QProducts->execute();

        echo $QProducts->value('products_name');
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Below the main element of the function . It can help you.

```
public function OrderProduts() {
          $prod_array = $this->orderResult['Cart']['contents'];

          foreach ($prod_array as $key => $value) {
            $QProducts = $this->db->prepare('select p.products_id,
                                                    pd.products_name
                                              from :table_products p,
                                                   :table_products_description pd
                                              where p.products_id = :products_id
                                              and p.products_id = pd.products_id
                                            ');

            $QProducts->bindInt(':products_id', $key);
            $QProducts->execute();

            echo $Products->value('products_name);
            echo $value ['qty'];
          }
       }
```

Comment: Try to show the array count with `count($this->products)`?

Comment: @NurMuhammad : count($this->products) = 3

Comment: if you iterate over an array with three values and only get one back that means something is breaking your loop and your script has probably crashed.  check your logs and/or enable error reporting.

Comment: Perhaps you may not have products with those IDs?

Comment: I have no error and the ID is correct

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the `products` works as pass by reference sort of a thing. 
Try assigning `products` to a variable,

```
$prodArray = $this->products
```

and iterate through the variable (`$prodArray`) instead of `$this->products`.

**Debugging**

Assign `product` in each iteration to a temprorary array (`$productsArrayTemp`) like this.

```
$productsArrayTemp = array(); //a temporary array.   
public function OrderProduts() {
    $prod_array = $this->orderResult['Cart']['contents'];

    foreach ($prod_array as $key => $value) {
        $QProducts = $this->db->prepare('select p.products_id,
                                            pd.products_name
                                      from :table_products p,
                                           :table_products_description pd
                                      where p.products_id = :products_id
                                      and p.products_id = pd.products_id
                                    ');

        $QProducts->bindInt(':products_id', $key);
        $QProducts->execute();

        //I am not too sure about the name of the object. 
        //But you need to push each and every object to an array.
        $this->productsArrayTemp[] = $Products;

  }
}
```

Then try counting that array,

`count($this->productsArrayTemp)`

If this results brings the expected number of results, then you can use this array (instead of `$this->products`) to access its sub objects.

The reason for doing this is to eliminate the fact that `$this->products` being overridden somewhere in your code.

I hope this helps.

Comment: tk but it take always one value : string(15) "Key=3 - Value=2"

Comment: Hi @mike, I know you did a `count($this->products)`. Was this just before the loop? If not try to do a `count` just before the loop. Looks like your `$this->products` getting overriden by by something else.

Comment: I inserted above the function.

Comment: Ok cool. Another point, is the where condition in your sql is correct ? ´where p.products_id = :products_id and p.products_id = pd.products_id` ? It looks both the same to me.

Comment: no, it's correct because you have  after  $QProducts->bindInt(':products_id', $key); - :products_id take the value of $key .

Comment: @mike I have edited my answer. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: $Products : what is the value, it 's not initialized ?

Comment: @mike That's why I mentioned in the comments, just above that line. It needs to be correct object / parameter name.